# Weighted average on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a new column which is a weighted average of the 2. and 3. columns.

2. column * 0.6 + 3.column*0.4, the issue is that the columns change weekly so I can't just use the column names, I want it to be the 2. and 3. columns every week.

I heard that df.iloc is the way to go, but I am not sure how to apply it on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python counts from `0`, so for select second cand third column use `1,2` in [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, 1] * 0.6 + df.iloc[:, 2] * 0.4
```

Comment: Thank you! My only issue is that I realised that adding a new row is not that easy.. for columns you just do df['new columns] = ..... but not sure how to add a row @jezrael

Comment: @JoshBob - for new row use `df.loc['new_row'] = df.iloc[1] * 0.6 + df.iloc[2] * 0.4`

Comment: @JoshBob - if default index alternative is `df.loc[len(df)] = df.iloc[1] * 0.6 + df.iloc[2] * 0.4 `